# adding column based on count and unique count in python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe as shown below.

```
type item
new apple
new apple
new io
new io
old apple
old io
old io 
old se
old pj
etc el
```

i need to create a new dataframe based on count and unique count

```
type    type_count  unique_item_count
new            4    2
old            5    4
etc            1    1
```

col 'type_count' is based on the frequency of labels in col'type'
col 'unique_item_count' is based on the unique count of labels present in col'item' for each unique label in col'type'

also if i add a new column

```
type    item    val
new apple       20
new apple       6
new io          5
new io          6
old apple       5
old io          6
old io          4
old se          5
old pj          3
etc el          2
```

and want a new dataframe with

```
type    type_count  unique_item_count   total_count
new             4                   2   37
old             5                   4   23
etc             1                   1   2
```

col 'total_count' is sum of amount present in the col'val' for each type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with list of tuples - first value specify new column name and second aggregate function, here [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
L = [('type_count','size'), ('unique_item_count','nunique')]
df = df.groupby('type', sort=False)['item'].agg(L).reset_index()
print (df)
  type  type_count  unique_item_count
0  new           4                  2
1  old           5                  4
2  etc           1                  1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked for me. also i have added another column 'val' and tried to get the sum. using L = [('Account_frequency_count','size'), ('unique_skill_count','nunique'),('total_vol','sum')]
rr = lis.groupby('Account', sort=False)['Skill1'].agg(L).reset_index()
print (rr) but it is concatenating the 'itemi in the 'total_count' column

Comment: @aim - Then need `df1 = df.groupby('type', sort=False).agg({'item':['size','nunique'], 'val':'sum'})` and `df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)`