# How to add datarame column of unique counts from another column against some but not all other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df looks like this:

```
  attribute  to_uniques  to_ignore
0         A           1         80
1         A           1         37
2         B           5         22
3         B           4         13
4         B           5         13
5         C           3         44

df = pd.DataFrame({'attribute': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'], 'to_uniques': [1, 1, 5, 4, 5, 3], 'to_ignore': [80, 37, 22, 13, 13, 44]})
```

And I want to add a column, `unique_count`, which counts the number of unique entries from `to_uniques` for each `attribute`, while ignoring other columns, like so:

```
  attribute  to_uniques  to_ignore  unique_count
0         A           1         80             1
1         A           1         37             1
2         B           5         22             2
3         B           4         13             2
4         B           5         13             2
5         C           3         44             1

desired_df = pd.DataFrame({'attribute': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'], 'to_uniques': [1, 1, 5, 4, 5, 3], 'to_ignore': [80, 37, 22, 13, 13, 44], 'unique_count': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]})
```

[This SO thread shows how to get half way there with .agg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366200/adding-column-based-on-count-and-unique-count-in-python), and I think this would be the code:

```
unique_agg= df.groupby('attribute', sort=False)['to_uniques'].agg([('attribute_count','size'), ('unique_item_count', 'nunique')]).reset_index()
```

But then I'd have to perform some kind of merge, but that kind of complexity risks mistakes. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do `transform`

```
df['new']=df.groupby('attribute')['to_uniques'].transform('nunique')
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!